# Array of bytes in BCD and int to array of bytes in bcd format

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I have a device that communicate via rs323. I receive an array of 8 bytes but in BCD format and I need to send in that way exp: Amount  8 bytes or 16 BCD I need a way how to convert amount to byte array?

if `amount = 500` I need to send byte array
`[0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0]` or in hex `00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00`

The same is if I need to send 2 bytes or 4 BCD! Now to enter an int number 10 and convert to 2 bytes 00 10?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: So this is _full_ BCD rather than _packed_? Then it's very simple - create an `byte[]` - this will automatically be filled with zeros. Then, iteratively, divide the number you have by `10` and set the remainder to the high end of the array...

Comment: can you add the example for bytes array to bcd int and int to bytes array

Comment: If 500 would end in { 05, 00, 00 } why would 10 be { 00, 10 } rather than { 01, 00 }? You need to make up your mind whether each byte is meant to be two digits or one...

Comment: each byte is meant to be two digits that is correct